# How to output value in textarea using JSTL in JSP

Tags: jsp, jstl

I'm using JSTL in jsp and want to output value in textarea

```
<tr>
    <th scope="row">SMS Before Inst</th>
    <td colspan="7"><textarea cols="20" rows="5" placeholder="SMS Content" id=smsMessage name="smsMessage">
        Time setting is
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${CTSSessionCode=='M'}">
                Morning 
            </c:when>
            <c:when test="${CTSSessionCode=='E'}">
                 Everning
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                OTHER
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>   
        Date
        <c:out value="${requestDate}" ></c:out> 
        ,We will contact later
    </textarea></td>
</tr>
```

within, CTSSessionCode = M is Morning, CTSSessionCode = E is Everning, and requestDate is date, but when i run it it output is blank and space character.

How to fix the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this structure the `<textarea>`:

```
<textarea>
value
</textarea>
```

You can try with this:

```
<textarea>value</textarea>
```

And move `<c:choose>` condition outside the `<textarea>`:

```
<c:set var="myVar" value="OTHER"></c:set>

<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${CTSSessionCode=='M'}">
        <c:set var="myVar" value="Morning"></c:set>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${CTSSessionCode=='E'}">
        <c:set var="myVar" value="Everning"></c:set>
    </c:when>
</c:choose>

<tr>
    <th scope="row">SMS Before Inst</th>
    <td colspan="7">
        <textarea cols="20" rows="5" placeholder="SMS Content" id=smsMessage name="smsMessage">Time setting is ${myVar} Date ${requestDate}, We will contact later</textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
```